# How to separate system icons in top bar

Tags: gnome, top-bar

I would like to separate the system icons in the top bar, that is wifi, bluetooth, sound and battery, to have 4 different clickable icons.

I saw this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/, but it doesn't work in Ubuntu 19.10.
I have other extensions installed, so I know how to set them, and I'm sure I did nothing wrong installing the extension. In fact, in the comments of that extension, I'm not the only one complaining that it doesn't work right now.

Is there any other way to do it?

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Did you enable GNOME Shell integration https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation as well as install the extension? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another extension to do it.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2416/panel-indicators/.

Anyone who need to do this, you can install that extension

Answer (score 1):

The perfect answer is `Big Sur Status Area` which is compatible with the new `Gnome 42` and is a fork of a fork (double fork) of the old `Panel Indicators`:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4085/big-sur-status-area/

This:
https://github.com/Ordissimo/Big-Sur-StatusArea
is a fork of:
https://github.com/Fausto-Korpsvart/Big-Sur-StatusArea
which is a fork of:
https://github.com/lvitals/panel-indicators

There is a major bug with this extension that I promptly reported on GitHub:
https://github.com/Ordissimo/Big-Sur-StatusArea/issues/95
I hope it will be useful to someone.