# RE: How to separate system icons in top bar - Gnome 42

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

Referring to the link:

[How to separate system icons in top bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229244/how-to-separate-system-icons-in-top-bar)

I would like to separate the system icons in the top bar, that is wifi, bluetooth, sound and battery, to have 4 different clickable icons.
Of this type, I have not found an extension compatible with Gnome 42.
Is there one compatible with Gnome 42?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfect answer is `Big Sur Status Area` which is compatible with the new `Gnome 42` and is a fork of a fork (double fork) of the old `Panel Indicators`:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4085/big-sur-status-area/

This:
https://github.com/Ordissimo/Big-Sur-StatusArea
is a fork of:
https://github.com/Fausto-Korpsvart/Big-Sur-StatusArea
which is a fork of:
https://github.com/lvitals/panel-indicators

There is a major bug with this extension that I promptly reported on GitHub:
https://github.com/Ordissimo/Big-Sur-StatusArea/issues/95
I hope it will be useful to someone.